Can I get seqno of a sender address in FunC smart contract of TON blockchain?


I want to fetch seqno of a sender address in FunC for relay protection purpose.
How to get it ? 
() recv_internal(int msg_value, cell in_msg_full, slice in_msg_body) impure {
    if (in_msg_body.slice_empty?()) { ;; ignore empty messages
        return ();
    }

    slice cs = in_msg_full.begin_parse();
    int flags = cs~load_uint(4);

    if (flags & 1) { ;; ignore all bounced messages
        return ();
    }
    slice sender_address = cs~load_msg_addr();

    ;; HOW TO GET seqno OF  sender_address

Thank you

Please describe what do you want to protect from. seqno is designed to be known to the sender and only they can set it; what you may be looking for is query_id, but I can only be sure if you provide more details
